# Searching for article link by keywords

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to search for a particular article on the website using BeautifulSoup. Ideally my script should allow me to find articles based on random keyword in the article titles and if found, return the corresponding article link.  The [example site](http://www.tabula.ge/en) contains article that has keyword `security council` in [this link](http://www.tabula.ge/en/story/90354-kandelaki-georgian-un-mission-yet-to-call-security-council-meeting) but so far I was unable to find it via `soup.find_all(text="security council")`.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!